# Force GitHub to import and track empty directories

Tags: github, svn, import, gitignore

I used GitHub's "import repository" functionality to import my repository from SVN to GitHub.

But, it did not import the "tmp" and "vendor" directories (as I've just discovered, maybe other directories too), apparently because they're empty.

Is there any way to force GitHub to import them all regardless?

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't track empty directories.  Add a .gitkeep file (no Git significance, any file can be used) to the directory.

Comment: But my codes are in SVN not Git and I want to import them by GitHub importer to Git.

Comment: Add files to the empty subfolders in SVN, then Git will import them.